# How to extend a final class in Java

Tags: java, static, final

Here is my problem actually I'm facing now. 
I have a class, let's say `Foo` and this class defines a method called `getBar` that returns a `Bar` instance. The class `Bar` is defined inside `Foo` and and is declared `public static final`. What I want to do is to define a class `MyFoo` that extends `Foo` but I also want to extend `Bar` with `MyBar` by adding my own functionalities (methods, properties,etc). 
I also want `getBar` to return `MyBar`.

The problem is `Bar` is final. Here is an illustration of what I want to do :

```
public class Foo {

  Bar bar = new Bar();

  public Bar getBar(){
      return bar;
  } 

   ....

   public static final class Bar {

    } 
}
```

What I want to do is :

```
public class MyFoo extends Foo {


   public MyBar getBar(){ // here I want to return an instance of MyBar

   }

  public static final class MyBar extends Bar { // That's impossible since Bar is final

  } 
}
```

How can I achieve that?

[EDIT] I am adding more details to my question. 
I am actually developing a plugin for Jenkins and after searching, I realize there is a plugin that offers the base functionalities that I want to do, `Foo` and `Bar`. I want to custom `Foo` and `Bar`,  so it can fits my needs. 
Foo is the main class of the plugin and extends a class called Builder. Foo defines a method called `perform` which contains all the operations for performing a build. 
`Bar` contains operations for configurations purposes and Foo needs Bar to get those informations.

So what I want to do is to extend Foo with `MyFoo` and add some configurations with `MyBar`. And as you see, `MyFoo` will need to get those configuations by calling `getBar();`

The second thing is I have no control of the instanciation of `MyFoo` and `MyBar`

What blocks me, is that I cannot extend Bar. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Since the `final` modifier prevents you from subclassing `Bar`, I'd recommend "wrapping" it.

Comment: If `Bar` is a `final class` it is usually for some good reason, e.g. pehaps because some invariants of `Foo` requires that. So I won't do that, or at least you should precisely understand all the relevant source code, and perhaps rewrite it.

Comment: Ask the developer of `Bar` to make it non-final or use delegation as mre suggests.

Comment: Ideally in such a case, `Bar` would implement an interface `IBar`, with the rest of the app coded against the interface. Using `final` on a simple class that's not completely internal to a design is probably a design smell. (Like on a class returned to clients of an API.)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, guys. How can I "wrap" Bar?

Comment: @Dimitri: You can't.  Meaning, you can wrap the class (`MyBar` holds and instance of `Bar`, implements the same methods by calling bar, as in: `foo() { return bar.foo(); }`), but that doesn't help you, since you want to be able to return `MyBar` from `MyFoo.getBar()`.  Not sure why that was a suggestion...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can't, basically. It looks like the developer who designed `Bar` intended for it not to be extended - so you can't extend it. You'll need to look for a different design - possibly one which doesn't use inheritance so much... assuming you can't change the existing code, of course.

(It's hard to give more concrete advice without knowing more about the real goal here - the design of the overall system.)

Comment: Well, I am actually developing a plugin for Jenkins and the thing is Foo and Bar has a lot functionalities that I want to extend. That would prevent me rewrite the same code of Foo and Bar

Comment: @Dimitri: That doesn't really give us enough information to know whether it would be reasonable to use composition instead of inheritance, for example.

Comment: `Foo` and `Bar` were designed deliberately so that you could not extend them.  You don't really have an alternative.

Answer (score 17):

You can't extend a class that is declared `final`. However you can create an intermediate class, called `Wrapper`. This Wrapper will basically contain an instance of the original class and provide alternative methods to modify the state of the object according what you want to do.

Of course this will not give access to the private & protected fields of the `final` class, but you can use its getters and setters methods, combined with the new methods & fields you declared in the `Wrapper` class to get the result you want to, or something relatively close.

Another solution is not to declare `final` a class if there is no valid reason to do it.

Answer (score 10):

You can't extend a `final` class - that's the purpose of the `final` keyword.

However, there are (at least) two work-arounds:

1. The class is in the Jenkins project, which is open source, so you can just download the project, make the changes you want to the class and re-build the jar
2. Somewhat of a hack, but you could use a library like [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) to replace the implementation of the class in memory

Comment: Why would someone make a class final? It may sound like a terrible question but I'm new to programming. 
I was trying to extend the Scanner class (just to see if I could) and I saw it wouldn't work. My friend told me it was because the Scanner class was final. 
Let's say theoretically it wasn't final and somebody did extend it. 
What would be the issue since any variables that are changed within the child class doesn't have to change the parent class? Etc. Idk

Comment: I know it has something to do with the Scanner class being overridden but I wouldn't even know how to overwrite it if it wasn't final and I tried.

Answer (score 5):

Probably what you want is a Proxy. It's easy to implement. This is a great article: http://blog.frankel.ch/the-power-of-proxies-in-java

Comment: can not reach this website now ?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot extend final classes, that is the point of declaring classes final. You can define an interface that both the final class inherit from and a wrapper class that delegates calls to the wrapped final class. The question is then why to make the class final in first place.

Answer (score 0):

For example we cannot add a StringBuffer in the TreeSet Collection, because
TreeSet is not child of the Interface Comparable:

```
public class Main(){
public static void main(String[] args){
   TreeSet treeSetSB = new TreeSet();
   treeSetSB.add(new StringBuffer("A"));  //error, Comparable is not implemented
}
```

But we can use a wrapper to implement the Comparable:

```
class myWrap implements Comparable{
    TreeSet treeset;
    public myWrap() {
        this.treeset=new TreeSet<>();

    }
    public TreeSet getTreeset() {
        return treeset;
    }
    public void setTreeset(TreeSet treeset) {
        this.treeset = treeset;
    }
}


public class Main(){
public static void main(String[] args){

   myWrap myWrap =new myWrap();
   TreeSet myTrs  =myWrap.getTreeset();
   myTrs.add("b");   // no error anymore
   myTrs.add("a");
   myTrs.add("A");
   System.out.println(myTrs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it implements some interfaces, [Decorator Design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) could solve the Problem.