# Is it possible to extend a final class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, final, extends

> **On possible duplicate:**
>
> This thread is not asking *how* to extend a `final` class. It is asking
>   *why* a class declared as `final` could possibly extend another class.

---

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181578/use-of-final-class-in-java) thread:

> A `final` class is simply a class that **can't be extended**.

However, I have a helper class which I declared to be `final` and `extends` another class:

```
public final class PDFGenerator extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    private static Font font;

    private PDFGenerator() {
        // prevent instantiation
    }

    static {
        try {
            BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(
                "/Trebuchet MS.ttf",
                BaseFont.WINANSI,
                BaseFont.EMBEDDED
            );

            font = new Font(baseFont, 9);

        } catch(DocumentException de) { 
            de.printStackTrace();

        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static ByteArrayOutputStream generatePDF() throws DocumentException {            
        Document doc = new Document();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baosPDF = new ByteArrayOutputStream();        
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, baosPDF);

        try {           
            // create pdf

        } catch(DocumentException de) {
            baosPDF.reset();
            throw de;

        } finally {
            if(doc != null) {
                doc.close();
            }

            if(pdfWriter != null) {
                pdfWriter.close();
            }
        }

        return baosPDF;
    }
}
```

Eclipse does not detect anything wrong with it. I have tested the class and the PDF was successfully generated without error.

Why was I able to `extend` a `final` class when I should not be able to in theory?

(I am using Java 7 if that matters.)

Comment: Try *extending* `PDFGenerator `. A final class can extend classes but it cannot be extended by other classes

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294629/how-to-extend-a-final-class-in-java

Comment: A `final` class that extends another class is not the same thing as another class that extends a `final` class - it's exactly the other way around.

Comment: Probably, it's problem with English, not with Java :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `Class` marked as `final` can extend another `Class`, however a `final Class` can not be extended.

Here is an example:

**This is allowed**

```
public class Animal {

}

public final class Cat extends Animal {

}
```

**This is *not* allowed**

```
public final class Animal {

}

public class Cat extends Animal {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`PDFGenerator` cannot be extended as it is marked final. You are extending `PdfPageEventHelper` which is not marked final.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that [`PdfPageEventHelper`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPageEventHelper.html) is not `final` (and this javadoc confirms it), so you can `extend` it, still you can't extend this new class `PDFGenerator`.

You may try to do it, though:

```
private Object abacaba = new PDFGenerator() {
};
```

Then you'll get compilation error:

> BlahBlah.java:n: error: cannot inherit from final PDFGenerator

Answer (score 1):

> Why was I able to extend a final class when I should not be able to in theory?

You weren't. your final class extended another class, it wasn't extended itself.

final classes (String is an example) are 'protected' against being inherited. You can not extend them.

In your example, try creating a new class, that does extend your final class:

```
public class A extends PDFGenerator{}
```

and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Note that **`PDFGenerator extends PdfPageEventHelper`**. That means that PDFGenerator is final but PdfPageEventHelper is not a final class. If you try to extend the PDFGenerator, then you will get exceptions if not errors.

Comment: Error or exception comes when your program runs. If you try to extend a final class, your code will not even compile.

Answer (score 1):

`PdfPageEventHelper` class is not made as final and hence you are able to extend that class. The final class cannot be extended.

If you try to extend `PDFGenerator` class which you have made as final then you will see that you are not able to extend that as its marked **final**.

Answer (score 1):

You have extended the `PdfPageEventHelper` (It must not be final i'm sure), `PDFGenerator` is decleared as final so the class `PDFGenerator` can't be extended by any class.Try extending `PDFGenerator` you won't be able to extend.

Answer (score 0):

No and defiantly not, `final` keyword is known in java as is used to restrict the user. It can be applied on variable method and class;

**Constant Variable:** (for all primtive and String) If you make any variable as final, you cannot change the value.

**Method:** If you make any method as final, you cannot override it.

**Class:** If you make any class as final, you cannot extend it.

It totally depends on requirements which object should/must set as final.

**Reason of using final:** It ensures the thread safety for field/method or class,

Comment: If you make a PRIMITIVE variable as final, you cannot change the value. if you make an OBJECT final, you can not re-reference it, but in a lot of cases, you will be able to change the value.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about Constant Variable, As far I know (programming depth is still unknown) this final means the Object should be initialize in same time it get defined. If you make collection you are able to add object but cannot re-initialize.

Comment: a simple pojo as well. as long as all it's members are not final, and provide setters, you'll be able to change it's value.

Comment: For POJO you need `this.foo = foo` which is not allowed. because you have `final Object foo= this.some();`, isn't it?

Comment: I'll give an example: public class Person(){ private String name; public Person(String name){ this.name = name;} public void setName(String name){ this.name = name;} public String getName(){ return this.name; } public static void main(String[] args){ final Person p = new Person("Bob");
System.out.println(p.getName()); p.setName("Kurt"); System.out.println(p.getName());
}}
you change the value, since even though p is final, name is not.

Comment: We are talking same thing again and again ;), As i mentioned you cannot do  `p= new Person("");` again or after define it, because it is final. Read in the answer when you make class as final it means you are restricting it `not being extend` as same case about collections i talked about.

Comment: true, but my responses are based on this comment in your answer: "If you make any variable as final, you cannot change the value."

Comment: Yes, its for non-primitive!

Comment: when it's not a primitive, you can change it's value. You just can't change it's reference.