# In java 1.8, WTookit class is final. So we can not extend it. Please tell me is there any way to extend this class?

Tags: java, final, extends

I am using java 1.8. And I came to know that WToolkit is final in java 1.8. But I need to extend this class. Could you please tell me ways to extend this class? I read articles related to javaagent mechanism. If any one knows about agent mechanism, please explain.

Comment: no by defination , final class means it cannot be extended. Could you tell why you want to do so, i believe your functionality can be achieved by some other way.You can consider wraping it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extend a final class in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294629/how-to-extend-a-final-class-in-java)

Comment: There is no class named `WToolkit` in the public API of the JDK. Do you mean the class [`sun.awt.windows.WToolkit`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/awt/windows/WToolkit.java?av=f)? That is an internal class in the JDK that you [should not be using](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, specifically?  There are probably better ways to do whatever it is that do not require extending a final class in a private API.

Comment: X-Y problem? Why do you think you need to extend this class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javaagent to inject code into any Java method, thereby changing its behavior, similar to overriding it in an extended class. See [Tutorials about javaagents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898566/tutorials-about-javaagents). Good chance there is an easier solution to what you are trying to achieve. What *are* you trying to achieve?