# Synonym for Integer type?

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java program that implements some program analysis. As part of this, I want a type for representing "values" in the programs that I'm analysing. Values, for my purposes, are just integers. However, I would rather not use the `int`/`Integer` types in my code, because `int`/`Integer` are not a very descriptive names. I would rather write `Value`. I would then *like* to write

```
class Value extends Integer {}
```

and be done. But this doesn't work because `Integer` is a final class. So my current solution is to give my `Value` class an `int` field and then manually implemented all the various standard methods:

```
class Value {
  int val;
  public String toString() {...}
  public int hashCode() {...}
  public boolean equals(...) {...}
  ...
}
```

This feels like overkill when I'm really just looking for class that behaves like `Integer` but has a more descriptive name.

What are my options here?

Comment: Why would *Value* be more descriptive than *Integer*? Imo it's even more vague.

Comment: and from the "not so descriptive Integer name" perspective, a `Double`, `Long` etc. could be technically also a value, so how would `Value` be more descriptive then `Integer`?

Comment: So the reason you want to "subclass" `Integer` is not because you'd like to change its behavior but to just change its name? That is not what subclassing is intended for. Just stick with `Integer`.

Comment: @YaroslavRudykh Yes that's right, I want to subclass `Integer` just to change its name, so that my code is more readable.

Comment: @Manu Yes *Value* is rather a vague word in general, but in my scenario, it is more descriptive than *Integer* because integers are used for all sorts of other things in my program, like loop counters. I think a type signature like `f(int i, Value v)` carries more useful information than just `f(int i, int v)`.

Comment: @KevinEsche No, in my setting, I know that a `Value` is always an `Integer`, not a `Double` etc. I just don't want to advertise this fact throughout my program. I would like to retain the option of changing the implementation of `Value` to a double or a boolean, without having to do a big find/replace throughout my entire program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend a final class in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294629/how-to-extend-a-final-class-in-java)

Comment: @JohnWickerson The problem that you descriped with the function `f` is rather not what the type describes, it´s rather that the information lacks are the variable and function name.

Comment: @KevinEsche Hm. Perhaps this is my background as a functional (OCaml) programmer showing through. To my mind, it's better/easier to make readable code by choosing good *types* for variables than good *names* for variables. This is because types *have* to be kept up-to-date, but names can rot.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap almost anything in a proxy:

```
class Value<T extends Number> extends Number {

    final T v;

    public Value(T v) {
        this.v = v;
    }

    @Override
    public int intValue() {
        return v.intValue();
    }

    @Override
    public long longValue() {
        return v.longValue();
    }

    @Override
    public float floatValue() {
        return v.floatValue();
    }

    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        return v.doubleValue();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return v.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return v.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return v.equals(obj);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I want. I want to obscure the fact that my `Value` is being implemented as an `Integer`. Your `Value<Integer>` would advertise that fact to everyone.