# How to extend a final class?(Reflection, Javassist)

Tags: java, reflection, bytecode, javassist

I have a .JAR file and it has tons of classes. One, that I need is set as final, so I cannot extend it. There is one method, that I basically have to extend and fix, otherwise everything breaks. How can I do that? I know Reflection and Javassist can be used for this, but I have no idea how. Any other tool is also acceptable, as long as it works.

Comment: Have a look over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294629/how-to-extend-a-final-class-in-java

Comment: Seen it, there is no example. I know it's not possible using Java normally, but I still need to get it done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use *reflection* to modify existing class definitions.

If the licence of that JAR allows you to,  I would suggest a different solution: **decompile** that one class; drop the *final* keyword; and rebuild class and JAR file.

That is the only *robust* way to solve your problem.

Comment: Which one did you try? And just for the record - we are not talking open source, where you could simply download the source?

Comment: Using JD-GUI, Luyten. Actually, it's a little bit of white-hat hacking :)

Comment: One other thought: do you know about the **implementation** of that class? What I mean is: would there be a chance to completely replace it with your own code? Or are the "real" functions in that class important to you?

Comment: Thought about it. But there is a signature algorithm in that class, I thought about copy pasting it in my code, but decompiler messes it up real good. Now that I looked closer at it, I think my problem is quite different - I need to actually remove a method from that class and it should work fine. Because now I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError for some random class. I think I will create a new StackOverflow post, it will get too off-topic

Comment: @Gintas_ Just use the Krakatau disassembler. That can handle anything, even classes which are impossible to decompile. If you're feeling brave, you can also use a hex editor. Removing the final flag is a single bit flip at a fixed offset, so it's easy to do in a hex editor.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a wrapper around the Final class for example and extend the functionality,for example :

```
public class YourClass {
    private FinalClass finalClass;

    public YourClass {
        finalClass = new FinalClass():
    }

    public void yourMethod() {
        finalClass.methodInFinalClass();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Final classes are marked final for a reason, so ideally you should not try to modify the class. You should consider moving to other APIs or write your own solution class for your case.