# How to remove a method from a compiled Java class/jar file?

Tags: java, reflection, bytecode, javassist

I have a JAR file and there is a static class, I can't decompile it, it gets messed up. There is one method in it, that returns a class, that doesn't exist. No idea how, but I'm getting `NoClassDefFoundError`. Even though I'm not using that method, it still crashes. So I need to somehow just remove it and it should work fine. I know Reflection or Javassist could be used, but no idea how.

Note, that this is obviously **not** for production release, just some white-hat hacking.

Comment: Is it related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579166/how-to-extend-a-final-classreflection-javassist/39579401#39579401.If yes,you could have continued the discussion there..:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mistaken: if that method would never be called, then the JVM would **most likely not** try to load that class.

You see, the whole point of class loading - it happens *lazy*; when you load class X, and X needs Y, Z ... then Y and Z are only loaded when some code is executed that requires Y, Z to be loaded.

In other words: that NoClassDefFound error actually tells you that **something** (maybe a static init somewhere in your JAR) is calling that method.

Thus, the solution is not to "cut out" that one method (that would simply lead to another exception, like MethodNotFound!). Instead, you should try to create a **dummy** class to not run into that exception at all. Or: your JAR is missing at least one of its dependencies. You can try to *resolve* that dependency - maybe you can find the class somewhere, or, you "build" your own version of it (the second idea might be probably **hard** to get correct).

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that... Building my own version of it worked, but I had to use JVM param `-noverify`. God damn this was scammy mess, but thanks bro

Comment: Feel free to express your gratitude by accepting then. And/or upvoting that other answer of main. I am close to hit the daily limit; and I like hitting *that* wall ;-)

Comment: “never” is too strong, given that you didn’t specify a specific JVM. There is a big freedom in the specification regarding the time when a JVM tries to resolve a class. Lazy class loading is not mandated by the specification, this is often confused with the lazy *initialization* that is guaranteed. For Oracle/OpenJDK, it’s true that it doesn’t try to resolve the return type of a method that is never invoked, but having a (conditional) code path that *might* invoke it, can already trigger the class loading during verification.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your input. I changed my wording accordingly.

Comment: I’d change “is calling that method” to “is potentially calling that method”, then, it’s incorporating the loaded-by-verifier scenario without going too much into detail.

Answer (score 1):

GhostCat already explained why your problem is not removing a method. But I figured I should answer the original question in case anyone else was wondering.

The best way to remove a method from a classfile is to disassemble it with [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau), delete the method you want from the `.j` file, and reassemble it. This method allows you to edit any classfile, no matter how strange. (If you find any valid classfiles that the Krakatau disassembler can't handle, please file a bug).

When disassembling, you may also want to pass the `-roundtrip` option. This isn't required for correctness, but it prevents the constant pool from being rearranged, reducing the binary diff of the resulting classfile. On the other hand, `-roundtrip` also makes it a lot harder to locate the method you want in the `.j` file.