# Override class noted "final" in vendor

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I want to override a class from the JMS/serializer bundle. Unfortunately this class is marked "final" and I can't override it. What would be the best method to circumvent this problem please?
I'm on symfony5.4

Here is the class I want to override :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace JMS\Serializer\Handler;

use JMS\Serializer\GraphNavigatorInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\Visitor\SerializationVisitorInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\XmlSerializationVisitor;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface as TranslatorContract;

use function get_class;

 final class FormErrorHandler implements SubscribingHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var TranslatorInterface|null
     */
    private $translator;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $translationDomain;
```

Comment: You don't. That is the meaning of final.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294629/how-to-extend-a-final-class-in-java

Comment: You may want to use a [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

Comment: @MarkusZeller  thank you for your answer, unfortunately this class was not marked "final" before and I had overrided this class. Now that I've upgraded the bundle, my override no longer works and my app crashes.

Comment: Why do you want to extend it? Usually, you should decorate it nowadays

Comment: @NicoHaase the problem is that when I create the decorator, the formErrorHandler class of the fosRestBundle expects to receive a class from the type JMS/FormErrorHandler and not from my decorator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I overridden the FormErrorHandler class from FOS/SerializerbUndle and then I overridden the formErrorHandlere class from JMS which I call in my overload of FOS/FormErrorHandler. it works perfectly

Comment: Hi @oracle972 it would hel people if you explain how did you do it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can not override the final classes as long as the package author does not provide a functionality to replace the final class with a custom implmentation.

by taking a look at the source code of the package, you can do so. the `SerializeBuilder` constructor is something like:

```
public function __construct(?HandlerRegistryInterface $handlerRegistry = null, ?EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher = null)
```

which clearly means that you can add your custom handler.

and due to the [documentation](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers#subscribing-handlers) you can implement your own handler easily.

```
$builder
    ->configureHandlers(function(JMS\Serializer\Handler\HandlerRegistry $registry) {
        $registry->registerSubscribingHandler(new MyHandler());
    })
;
```

Comment: hello @hassan I want to override FormErrorHandler class from JMS bundle. This class is used directly in the FormErroHandler class of the FOS/RestBundle. When I create a custom class like in your example, I get an error like: FOS/restBundle expects an instance of JMS/FormErrorHandler , Custom class Given

Comment: can you give an example of how you implement the RestBundle? from what I can see RestBundle is relying on HandlerRegistryInterface, which means that you can easily use your custom implementation, you will need to implement the same interface too to be accepted by RestBundle

Comment: I didn't modify the RESTBundle, I only override the FormErrorHandler class from the JMS bundle

Comment: I know, I mean you need to share how do you use RestBundle in your code, however, the point is that you can extend the functionality of RestBundle too

Comment: I use the restBundle in a rather classic way. I installed the bundle and added the annotations on my classes. Then when an error occurs, the fos bundle creates an error response. I don't know what else to tell you. You think I can directly override the FormErrorHandler class from FOSBundle without using the class from JMS?

Comment: You can inject your own Handler to RestBundle, can you check this? https://fosrestbundle.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/4-exception-controller-support.html?highlight=Serializer

Comment: I finally found a solution. I overridden the FormErrorHandler class from FOS/SerializerbUndle and then I overridden the formErrorHandlere class from JMS which I call in my overload of FOS/FormErrorHandler

Comment: do you mean by overriding that you edited the code within the package itself?

Comment: no of course, I recreated the FOS/FormErrorHandler class in my application. I don't know the exact term in English

Comment: OK great, that's whatt I was talking about in my submitted solution, to implement the custom handler by your self